# Cloud Data Fusion - trim quotes for all columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a csv file in GCS with fields with hundreds of columns enclosed in quotes, like below :

> "John","Doe","5/15/2021  7:18:26 PM"

I need to load this to BigQuery using Data fusion, created a pipeline. My question is

1. How do I trim quotes from these the columns in the Wrangler? I don't find much documentation for this, rather than the basic things
2. How do I apply this rule for all the columns in one shot.

Please guide me, any good reading on these kind of operations will also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purposes I used your sample data and add a few more entries.

[image]

### Remove quotes

If your data looks like this and your objective is to just remove the quotes from your data, what you can do is:

- Click the drop down arrow beside **body**
- Select Find and replace
- At find put " and leave replace as blank

[image]

Your output will look like this:

[image]

---

### Parse CSV to split into columns

You can then convert your CSV to columns:

- Click the drop down beside **body**
- Select Parse -> CSV
- A pop up will appear and select "Comma"

[image]

This will tell your wrangler to read it as a CSV and split the comma to columns. But the original data will remain at column **body**.

[image]

To delete **body**:

- Select body by ticking the check box at the right
- Click the drop down beside **body**
- Select **Delete column**

[image]

Your data should now look like this:

[image]